# Javascript Regex for Czech language

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create a Regular expresion function, to check if a input includes only the Regex characters. If not, then alert the user.

Using the following code:

```
var valueOfName = document.querySelector("#frmform-name").value;

if (!(/^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUQRSTUVWXYZáčďéěíňóřšťúůýžÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤÚÝŽ]+$/.valueOfName)){
   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".location").offset().top
   }, 2000);
   setTimeout(function() { alert("Jméno musí obsahovat pouze písmena."); }, 2000);
        return false;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to find a-z, A-Z and special characters like č,á,ž...

But its still not working, does anyone have a clue how I can adjust it to make i work.

Comment: `.valueOfName` -> `.test(valueOfName)`. You fogot to specify the method.

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: Ok thanks that did it @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the [`RegExp#test`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) method against your `valueOfName` variable:

```
if (!(/^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUQRSTUVWXYZáčďéěíňóřšťúůýžÁČĎÉĚÍŇÓŘŠŤÚÝŽ]+$/.test(valueOfName))){
                                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```